# Are operators in core really defined circularly?

Tags: rust, operators

We can implement the traits in `core::ops` to define the behavior of operators for our types. The traits themselves are annotated with `#[lang  =...]` attributes so the compiler knows which traits and operators belong together.

For example, the `Add` implementation for primitive types looks like this (macro manually expanded and simplified from [here](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/1.25.0/src/libcore/ops/arith.rs#L100-L115)):

```
impl Add for i32 {
    type Output = i32;

    fn add(self, other: i32) -> i32 {
        self + other
    }
}
```

To my surprise, the implementation uses the `+` operator internally, which presumably calls `self.add(other)`, resulting in an infinite recursion. Obviously, things do not happen like this because expressions like `3 + 4` (assuming no constant folding) work perfectly fine.

Now consider this naive implementation of the `Add` trait:

```
use std::ops::Add;

struct Foo;

impl Add for Foo {
    type Output = Foo;

    fn add(self, other: Foo) -> Foo {
        self + other
    }
}

fn main() {
    let two_foo = Foo + Foo;
}
```

The compiler warns that `function cannot return without recurring` and running this program in Debug mode properly stops with `fatal runtime error: stack overflow`.

How does the compiler know how to add two numbers without falling into a recursive loophole?

Comment: Possibly related: [Where are Rust's boolean and other primitive types implemented?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39335747/where-are-rusts-boolean-and-other-primitive-types-implemented).

Comment: @ljedrz more than related. Althoughs the question is totally different, the answers match very well. I'm not sure if this is a duplicate now, because the answers here add information that would not match your question.

Comment: I think this question is interesting on its own; in this case the source *is* available in the `std` docs and its link to the intrinsics is not obvious at all.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> How does the compiler know to add two numbers without falling into a recursive loophole?

Because the compiler is the compiler, and the compiler knows it doesn't need an `Add` implementation to add two numbers.  If it's doing constant folding, it just adds them.  If it's generating code, it tells LLVM to add them at runtime.

Those `Add` implementations aren't there to tell the compiler how to add numbers, they're to implement `Add` for numbers so that user code can add numbers via the `Add` trait just like any user-defined type.  If those implementations didn't exist, then you wouldn't be able to add numbers in generic methods, because they wouldn't implement `Add`.

To put it another way: `Add` is what the compiler uses when it doesn't otherwise know how to add things.  But it already knows how to add numbers, so it doesn't need them.  They're provided for consistency with other types.

Answer (score 5):

The implementations of `Add` that rely on the addition operator `+` in the end need to point to operations on primitives (eg. integers) and arithmetic operations on *those* are implemented using [compiler built-ins](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intrinsic_function).

What is more, the primitives themselves are compiler built-ins as well - note that you won't be able to find their sources in the `std` documentation.

The bottom line is that primitive types don't actually *need* the code provided by the implementations of `Add` and other artithmetic operators' traits at all - these functionalities are provided by the compiler's intrinsics. Their trait implementations are provided for the purposes of generics.