# Why is it allowed to have both immutable and mutable borrows of a vector of numeric types in one expression?

Tags: rust

`a` is a `Vec<i32>` which can be mutably and immutably referenced in one expression:

```rust
fn main() {
    let mut a = vec![0, 1];
    a[0] += a[1]; // OK
}
```

I thought this compiled because `i32` implements `Copy`, so I created another type that implements `Copy` and compiled it like the first example, but it fails:

```rust
use std::ops::AddAssign;

#[derive(Clone, Copy, PartialEq, Debug, Default)]
struct MyNum(i32);

impl AddAssign for MyNum {
    fn add_assign(&mut self, rhs: MyNum) {
        *self = MyNum(self.0 + rhs.0)
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut b = vec![MyNum(0), MyNum(1)];
    b[0] += b[1];
}
```

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=d8ad987a94f1c70092fb8b45e536152d)

```
error[E0502]: cannot borrow `b` as immutable because it is also borrowed as mutable
  --> src/main.rs:14:13
   |
14 |     b[0] += b[1];
   |     --------^---
   |     |       |
   |     |       immutable borrow occurs here
   |     mutable borrow occurs here
   |     mutable borrow later used here
```

1. Why does my `MyNum` not behave in the same way as `i32` even though it implements `Copy`?
2. Why can the vector be mutably and immutably referenced in one expression?

Comment: It works with an array instead of a `Vec`. Not sure why.

Comment: @trentcl: Probably because an array of `Copy` implements `Copy` but a `Vec` of `Copy` does not.

Comment: @rodrigo Good guess, but I don't think so. [It also works with `&mut [MyNum]`](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=fcfd3975442c96b83d6743b3cc1c8335)

Comment: @trentcl: Then... there is only one explanation left: Magic! (compiler magic, of course).

Comment: See also [Cannot borrow as immutable because it is also borrowed as mutable in function arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41189051/155423)

Comment: @eggyal the fully desugared version does not work: `MyNum::add_assign(IndexMut::index_mut(&mut b, 0), Index::index(&b, 1));`

Comment: @pretzelhammer: Yes, I noticed I was just assigning not add-assigning.

Comment: For `i32` neither the fully desugared version `i32::add_assign(IndexMut::index_mut(&mut a, 0), Index::index(&a, 1));` nor the partially desugared version `32::add_assign(&mut a[0], a[1]);` work. I think this may be a case of compiler magic like @rodrigo suggested...

Comment: As an aside, one can work around this with e.g. `let (lhs, rhs) = b.split_at_mut(1); lhs[0] += rhs[0];`.

Comment: Issue has been opened in: https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/72199

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe the thing you're seeing here is that [primitive types](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive/index.html) do not actually call their `std::ops` equivalents. Those `std::ops` may just be included for seamless trait extensions, etc. I think the blog post [*Rust Tidbits: What Is a Lang Item?*](https://manishearth.github.io/blog/2017/01/11/rust-tidbits-what-is-a-lang-item/) partially explains this.

I exported the MIR of your example [that works with primitive types](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=a09a469d1d7584443288f182149cb3cb). I got:

```
    bb5: {
        StorageDead(_9);                 // bb5[0]: scope 1 at src/main.rs:6:8: 6:9
        _10 = CheckedAdd((*_8), move _5); // bb5[1]: scope 1 at src/main.rs:6:5: 6:17
        assert(!move (_10.1: bool), "attempt to add with overflow") -> [success: bb6, unwind: bb4]; // bb5[2]: scope 1 at src/main.rs:6:5: 6:17
    }
```

I had a lot of difficulty exporting the MIR for the code that was erroring. Outputting MIR without borrow checking is new to me and I couldn't figure out how to do it.

[This](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=63c25725edd0e3accc72b6d325344eec) playground has a very similar thing, but compiles :)

It gives me an actual call to `add_assign`:

```
    bb3: {
        _8 = _9;                         // bb3[0]: scope 1 at src/main.rs:14:5: 14:9
        StorageDead(_10);                // bb3[1]: scope 1 at src/main.rs:14:8: 14:9
        StorageLive(_11);                // bb3[2]: scope 1 at src/main.rs:14:14: 14:22
        (_11.0: i32) = const 1i32;       // bb3[3]: scope 1 at src/main.rs:14:14: 14:22
                                         // ty::Const
                                         // + ty: i32
                                         // + val: Value(Scalar(0x00000001))
                                         // mir::Constant
                                         // + span: src/main.rs:14:20: 14:21
                                         // + literal: Const { ty: i32, val: Value(Scalar(0x00000001)) }
        _7 = const <MyNum as std::ops::AddAssign>::add_assign(move _8, move _11) -> [return: bb5, unwind: bb4]; // bb3[4]: scope 1 at src/main.rs:14:5: 14:22
                                         // ty::Const
                                         // + ty: for<'r> fn(&'r mut MyNum, MyNum) {<MyNum as std::ops::AddAssign>::add_assign}
                                         // + val: Value(Scalar(<ZST>))
                                         // mir::Constant
                                         // + span: src/main.rs:14:5: 14:22
                                         // + literal: Const { ty: for<'r> fn(&'r mut MyNum, MyNum) {<MyNum as std::ops::AddAssign>::add_assign}, val: Value(Scalar(<ZST>)) }
    }
```

How does the primitive case pass the borrow checker? Since `add_assign` is not called, the immutable reference can be dropped before the mutable reference is required. The MIR simply dereferences the needed location earlier on and passes it through by value.

```
    bb3: {
        _5 = (*_6);                      // bb3[0]: scope 1 at src/main.rs:6:13: 6:17
        StorageDead(_7);                 // bb3[1]: scope 1 at src/main.rs:6:16: 6:17
        ...
    }
```

Comment: You can export MIR fairly reliably without having to get borrowck to pass on nightly with the -Zdump-mir flag -- that'll create a directory with a bunch of mir dumps. I generally just go for the last one, e.g. in this case you could look at `mir_dump/rustc.main.002-001.SimplifyCfg-qualify-consts.after.mir`. See https://rustc-dev-guide.rust-lang.org/mir/debugging.html for more details.

Comment: Thanks! I don't think `playground` allows for this currently? It would be nice to be able to see a MIR on borrow check failures as in the case above.

Comment: It is not only `AddAssign` but also `Index` that seems to be relevant here. [This example](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=fcfd3975442c96b83d6743b3cc1c8335), which I linked in the question comments, also uses `AddAssign` but compiles fine. See also [Are operators in core really defined circularly?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50254315/3650362) which elaborates on the built-in-ness of certain operations on primitive types.

Comment: Yeah when I saw your comment I looked at the MIR, very strange. Clearly in your case the slice directly dereferences immediately (`_11 = &mut (*_7)[_12];`) - it never calls Index at all! Slices are also `primitive` magic! Lessons learned today.

Comment: Thanks! Is there any way to compile my second example? That is, I  want to compile a code that add-assign of a vector of my structure.

Comment: @Yohei Yes you can just assign `b[1]` to a variable first. The issue is with using the index in the same expression as the assignment.

Comment: @Yohei - as @trentcl discovered - you can cast to a slice and then the line works. `let slice = b.as_mut_slice(); slice[0] += slice[1];`.

Comment: Thanks!  The slice trick is very interesting. Anyway, I feel it is inconsistent and strange that this question is not well-defined by trait.

Comment: I posted an issue in rust because I thought as you, this is definitely strange. https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/72199